# Problems installing extlinux bootloader on a flash drive in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

My previous question [How to install extlinux on Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200934/how-to-install-extlinux-on-ubuntu-19-10) was closed as a duplicate with a link to similar topics. But there I did not find a solution to my problem. I apologize, but I have to ask for help again.

The software has booted. The **next step was to install the bootloader**. Detected that the Syslinux folder is located in / usr / lib / syslinux. Extlinux folder is not at all. To install the bootloader gave the command: sudo syslinux --install / boot / syslinux (the folder / boot / syslinux was created earlier)
Error: sudo: / usr / lib / syslinux: command not found

He gave **the command to copy the boot sector** to a USB flash drive:
dd if = / usr / lib / syslinux / mbr.bin of = / dev / sdd
Again the error: dd: failed to open '/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin': No such file or directory.

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*Command not found*" implies that you have not yet installed the minimum software required for the task. For example, did you successfully install the `extlinux` package? Your previous question was closed with a link to instructions to [how to enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) so that you could install the correct packages, not 'similar topics'.

Comment: Yes I did. Outwardly, everything was fine. There were no errors. Do you think the extlinux folder is missing due to my error? Okay, I'll try to repeat.

Comment: After running `sudo extlinux --install /boot/extlinux` the `Not a directory /boot/extlinux` error message has changed. In fact, there is such a directory.